# How to do a one tail pvalue calculate in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I have two arrays, one is an array of corrected values, x, and the other is an array of the original values(before a correction was applied), y. I know that if I want to do a two-tailed ttest to get the two-tailed pvalue I need to do this:

```
t_statistic, pvlaue = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(x, y, nan_policy='omit')
```

However this only tells me if the two arrays are significantly different from eachother. I want to show that the corrected values, x, are significantly less than y. To do this it seems like I need to get the one-tailed pvalue but I can't seem to find a function that does this. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390222/one-sided-t-test-for-linear-regression/43390714#43390714 The same logic here. Just pass the returning t_statistic to the survival function or cdf based on the direction of the hypothesis.

Comment: I tried passing the t_statistic in the sf this but it says that I need to arguments. This is really all of the information that I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider these two arrays:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
x, y = prng.normal([1, 2], 1, size=(10, 2)).T
```

An independent sample t-test returns:

```
t_stat, p_val = ss.ttest_ind(x, y, nan_policy='omit')
print('t stat: {:.4f}, p value: {:4f}'.format(t_stat, p_val))

# t stat: -1.1052, p value: 0.283617
```

This p-value is actually calculated from the cumulative density function:

```
ss.t.cdf(-abs(t_stat), len(x) + len(y) - 2) * 2
# 0.28361693716176473
```

Here, `len(x) + len(y) - 2`  is the number of degrees of freedom.

Notice the multiplication with 2. If the test is one-tailed, you don't multiply. That's all. So your p-value for a left tailed test is

```
ss.t.cdf(t_stat, len(x) + len(y) - 2)
# 0.14180846858088236
```

If the test was right tailed, you would use the survival function

```
ss.t.sf(t_stat, len(x) + len(y) - 2)
# 0.85819153141911764
```

which is the same as `1 - ss.t.cdf(...)`.

I assumed that the arrays have the same length. If not, you need to modify the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Quick question. Does the order I put x, y in the test_ind matter? for example I want to see if x is significantly larger than y. Do I order it x,y in the test_ind and then do a right tail test as discussed with the sf? Then if the value is <0.05 it is significantly larger than y...is this correct?

Comment: @ayhan Is this correct? ' ss.t.cdf(t_stat, len(x) + len(y) - 2) * 2 ' , how come we multiply the resulting p-value by 2? Doesn't this allow for a p-value larger than 1 ?

Comment: @hirschme For a two-tailed hypothesis test we calculate the area between -infinity and -absolute(t-value) and also the area between absolute(t-value) and inf. Since t-distribution is symmetrical you can calculate one of them and multiply by two. Of course each of these will return a value less than or equal to 0.5. However, I failed to mention in the post that if t is positive that calculation would be `(1 - ss.t.cdf(t_stat, len(x) + len(y) - 2)) * 2`.

Comment: @ayhan that makes sense, thank you. I just posted the same as a general question. Feel free to answer it. Else I will just delete it as it is no longer relevant